# How to iterate through an excel file with Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would like to append an empty list "city_names" and add all the names of a city in order from an excel file I have imported.

```py
city_names = []
for city in cities["City"]:
print("city")
print(city_names)`

should give me this result:
['Buenos Aires',
 'Toronto',
 'Pyeongchang',
 'Marakesh',
 'Albuquerque',
 'Los Cabos',
 'Greenville',
 'Archipelago Sea',
 'Walla Walla Valley',
 'Salina Island',
 'Solta',
 'Iguazu Falls']
```

I am not sure why it doesn't work.
The filename is 'cities'.

Comment: How did you open/read the excel file? What does your full code looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this snippet may help you.

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('Cities.xlsx') # put your filename
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Cities') # put sheet name

cities=[c.value for c in worksheet.col(0)] # expecting cities are in first column
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using panads:

```
import pandas as pd

filePath = 'cities.xlsx'  #your path to cities 
df = pandas.read_excel(filePath) #df = pandas.read_csv(filePath) if your file is in CSV format
city_names = df['city'].tolist()
```

You can now iterate through this list.